# Failing to get Karaf 4.2.6 to log using log4j2 with JsonLayout for a layout type

Tags: json, maven, logging, log4j2, apache-karaf

I have been at this all day and not getting it to work after trying so many combinations. At the end of the day, I am looking for an explicit list of steps to get JSON logging from Karaf. I have even gone through the Maven Karaf plugin source code trying to sort this out, though perhaps I didn't look far enough.

I am using Karaf 4.2.6. I am attempting to build a Karaf deployment using the karaf-maven-plugin, version 4.2.6.

If I change my `layout.type` for various appenders to `JsonLayout`, I get a stacktrace saying it can't load the JSON layout because I am missing a class. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider`.

I looked at the jar `org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/1.10.2` and found I needed 3 Jackson jars, Core v2.8.7, Annotations v2.8.0, and Databind v2.8.7.

I have been trying to get these files in `etc/startup.properties` with either the start level of 5 or the start level of 8 so that they are ready for `org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/1.10.2` when it starts. I made sure they were in the `system` folder in the correct place. Most of the time, if I did get them into `etc/startup.properties`, they had a start level of 30. I placed them in a feature with the correct start levels, but they were either started well after whatever used `startup.properties` or just never showed up. I tried many possibly combinations, `startupBundles`, `startupFeatures`, `bootFeatures`, but nothing got it in `startup.properties`. I could not figure out how the contents of `startup.properties` got generated. Sometimes the features I wanted for my application wouldn't even start because something about the configuration got blocked on setting up the logging if I just placed references to those jars in `startup.properties`, for example

`mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.7 = 5`

Below is my pom.xml with somethings from previous attempts commented out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
      <my_version>0.0.0</my_version>
      <myapp_common_version>0.0.0</myapp_common_version>
    </properties>    

    <groupId>com.me.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-karaf</artifactId>
    <version>${my_version}</version>
    <packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>

    <name>myapp-karaf</name>
    <description>myapp-karaf details</description>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Apache ServiceMix repository (for region) -->
        <repository>
            <id>apache.servicemix.m2</id>
            <name>Apache ServiceMix M2 repository</name>
            <url>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/m2-repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- OPS4J SNAPSHOT repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy</id>
            <name>OPS4J snapshot repository</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Apache SNAPSHOT -->
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots.deploy</id>
            <name>Apache snapshot repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <type>kar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.me.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-common-feature</artifactId>
            <version>${myapp_common_version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.me.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-feature</artifactId>
            <!-- Annoyingly this cannot come from an environment variable -->
            <version>${my_version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${env.MYAPP_SOURCE_HOME}/myapp-common/server/karaf/assembly</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/filtered-resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.6</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <startupBundles> <!--
                        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0</bundle>
                        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.7</bundle>
                        <bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.7</bundle> -->
                    </startupBundles>
                    <installedFeatures>
                    </installedFeatures>
                    <startupFeatures>
                        <feature>com.me.myapp/${my_version}</feature>
                    </startupFeatures>
                    <bootFeatures>
                        <feature>com.me.myapp.logging.provider/${myapp_common_version}</feature>
                        <!-- standard distribution -->
                        <!-- <feature>standard</feature> -->
                        <!-- minimal distribution -->
                        <!--<feature>minimal</feature>-->
                        <feature>jaas</feature>
                        <feature>shell</feature>
                        <feature>ssh</feature>
                        <feature>management</feature>
                        <feature>bundle</feature>
                        <feature>config</feature>
                        <feature>deployer</feature>
                        <feature>diagnostic</feature>
                        <feature>instance</feature>
                        <feature>kar</feature>
                        <feature>wrap</feature>
                        <feature>log</feature>
                        <feature>package</feature>
                        <feature>service</feature>
                        <feature>system</feature>

                    </bootFeatures>
                    <javase>1.8</javase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`com.me.myapp.logging.provider` contains the Jackson jars with the proper start level.

I am running my containers in Kubernetes and want standard log collection in Kubernetes to work. I am using using an extra plugin on the logs collector to at least separate things somewhat into a JSON format, but it is error prone and I'd rather just start with JSON formatted logs rather than processing later downstream so I can separate components of the log, such as person who did the operation, at the time of logging.

I have searched on Stack Overflow, have Googled, and found hints, but no explicit steps that lead to a solution. I realize there is not an explicit listing of files here, but, as I said, I went through many combinations. Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I will also post on the Karaf user group.

Comment: https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXLOGGING-260 fixes pax-logging-log4j2-extra, which is a fragment bundle that "brings" extra imports to original pax-logging-log4j2. Did you add this extra fragment? Karaf's https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/features/framework/src/main/feature/feature.xml doesn't include this extra fragment.

Comment: Added it, Still failing. Going to try a few things to see if I can at least get something work manually. I notice that the imports in extra have no versions in the optional imports, and I have a newer version of Jackson in my application. Perhaps my current problem comes from that, am going to look at the OSGi manifests of pax-log4j2 and extra.

Still trying to understand how things get into startup.properties. If you have any ideas @GrzegorzGrzybek, please let me know.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to check Pax Logging 1.11.x Karaf tests in https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/tree/pax-logging-1.11.x/pax-logging-it-karaf/karaf-it/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/it/karaf - there are tests for present and missing "extra" bundle.

Answer (score 6):

OK, after several days, I figured out everything that needed to be done. Thank you @GrzegorzGrzybek for the help.

I needed the following lines

```
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2-extra/1.11.4 = 8
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.10 = 8
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.10 = 8
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.10 = 8
```

added to my `etc/startup.properties`. If I just edited the file to add them, and made sure I had the files in the `system` repository, it would not work. No idea, some entry was not being made somewhere else in the `etc` configs so either the container wouldn't start, or some feature sets were being started up before the `wrap` handler was installed, so the whole container would grind to a halt.

I tried lots of combinations, but finally found how to get things into `etc/startup.properties`. I placed the bundles I wanted into their own feature with the start level I wanted them to have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.3.0" name="myapp-common-container-feature">
  <feature name="com.me.myapp.logging.provider" version="0.12.0" description="MyApp Logging Provider">
    <bundle start-level="8">mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.10</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="8">mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.10</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="8">mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.10</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="8">mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2-extra/1.11.4</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

Notice the `start-level` attribute.

Then, in my assembly POM, I put the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.me.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp-common-container-feature</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The important line here is `<scope>compile</scope>`. Features in the `compile` scope will be placed in `startup.properties` if placed in `<startupFeatures />` in the configuration for the Karaf Maven Plugin.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <startupFeatures>                
                    <feature>com.me.myapp.logging.provider/0.12.0</feature>
                  </startupFeatures>
```

Now the container starts up with JSON logging.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I followed [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545616/628006) but this was not sufficient as I had already another older version of Jackson in the OSGI container.

Here is what I did:

Added the log4j2 extra with the three Jackson libs (version 1.11.13 of Pax-Logging + jackson version 2.12.4) in the `startup.properties`:

```
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.12.4 = 6
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.12.4 = 6
mvn\:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.4 = 6
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2-extra/1.11.13 = 6
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.11.13 = 8
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/1.11.13 = 8
```

And in the `overrides.properties`:

```
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.12.4;range="[2,3)"
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.4;range="[2,3)"
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.12.4;range="[2,3)"
```

and only after this I was able to see my Json log properly formatted (with `JsonLayout` deprecated way).

I also tried the new way by trying to deploy bundle `log4j-layout-template-json` but it seems this lib is wrongly released (host fragment is referring to itself).

Answer (score 0):

I put these jars in system repository, installed using wraper and restarted karaf. It's worked for me:

```
bundle:install 'wrap:mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2-extra/1.11.4'
bundle:install 'wrap:mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.10'
bundle:install 'wrap:mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.10'
bundle:install 'wrap:mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.10'
```

Comment: Normally wrapper is for libraries that does not have the bundle manifest, but as far as I know the jackson and log4j extra are deployable in OSGI without need of "wrap".